# Consume SOAP service in .NET Core using SAML with signed XML

Tags: security, wcf, .net-core, soap

We are converting some code from .NET Framework to .NET Core. Some services are using SOAP messages with a signed header. Using SoapCore we've been abled to create a service which supports signed XML (and the necessary validations). However, we are now creating a client which should be able to consume such a service (in .NET Core).

Basic code (performing the request, no signing):

```cs
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://myserver/mysoapendpoint/"));
            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ISampleService>(binding, endpoint);
            var serviceClient = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            var result = serviceClient.Ping("hey");
```

I can't find any way to make the service send an XML. In .NET Framework we could do it the following way:

```cs
            using (ChannelFactory<ISampleService> factory = new ChannelFactory<ISampleServiceChannel>(tokenBinding, endpointAddress))
            {
                factory.Credentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = true;
                using (ISampleServiceChannel proxy = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(myToken))
                {
                    var result = proxy.Ping("hey");
                }
            }
```

Stuff like *CreateChannelWithIssuedToken* no longer seems to be implemented in .NET Core. If I could inject something which would sign the XML than I could do the writing myself. However, I'm unable to find the correct way to achieve this goal.

We cannot change to another implementation of security as we are not controlling the clients/services... (Clients from different organizations will interact this way...)

Many thanks for your replies.

Comment: I temporary solved it with creating a SOAP helper which actually creates the SOAP XML and signs it. I'm sending it manually now without using any of the built-in components such as ChannelFactory...

Comment: Congratulations. Would you mind sharing it with us? you could directly mark it as an answer.